# How do I stop softbody from bouncing up and down

Tags: physics, soft-body

So basically, as i apply a softbody to any object, it goes up and down repeatedly. I get that this is by default and it happens every time when the softbody has its default settings, but I'd like the object to not do that movement. Is there a way to fix this?
I'm a bit new to blender and dont really understand the softbody settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes down because of gravity, at first resisted by inertia, and then strengthened by inertia.  These forces are resisted by edge springs and goal settings, at first weak, pulling it to rest edge length and rest vertex position.  Eventually, springs and goal reach the same force as gravity + inertia, and then pull the vertices back upwards to rest position, at which point inertia continues pulling the vertices upwards, until all other forces counteract inertia.  Then we start all over again.

There are two options:

1. You can disable gravity.  If you don't want gravity to pull your softbodies downward, then you can set the force of gravity to 0,0,0, or just uncheck it, in properties/scene/gravity.  Or, you can set the field weight of gravity to 0 for that specific object in properties/physics/field weights.  If you don't get the ball rolling with gravity in the first place, it won't do that kind of oscillation.
2. You can increase damping.  Their are two kinds of damping, as implied by the explanation: goal damping and edge spring damping.  Goal damping is in properties/physics/goal/settings; edge spring damping is in properties/physics/edges.  The overwhelming force, in a default soft body cube, is goal, not springs, and so increasing the goal damping will have the largest effect.  Note that damping will **not** stop the oscillation from happening.  It will only make it die down more quickly.